# Problems when adding a fillable PDF form if the page is rotated

Tags: hyperref, rotating, landscape

I need to use the `TextField` command of the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package inside a `landscape` environment, but the input of the `TextField` is rotated according to the orientation of the current page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField{Text};
    \end{Form}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: The input is rotated]

**Is there any way to rotate the input horizontally?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a key rotation that you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[rotation=90]{Text};
    \end{Form}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And I looking for *rotate* in the manual and nothing useful came out, how silly I was, quack! Thanks for the answer! It was what I was looking for.