# Can I combine TextField (on a landscape page) with "long table"

Tags: longtable

My problem is as follows: I want to create a document in PDF format that contains checkboxes and Textfield that should be filled out by users. The Textfiles appear in tables in landscape mode. 
This means:

1. I want to have tables (using "longtables", because the tables stretch over several pages)
2. In said tables, I want to have TextFields that (in the produced PDF) can be filled out by a user

I used `\KOMAoptions{paper = landscape, pagesize}`so that the TextField orientation is correct but then long table would not work. When using the pdflandscape option instead, the Textfield are in the wrong orientation.

How can this be fixed ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{helvet}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\geometry{a4paper}
\geometry{portrait}
\geometry{margin=1.1in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round

%%% PACKAGES
\newcommand{\por}{A name}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\LayoutCheckField}[2]{\mbox{#2}\,#1}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\date{}
\author{}
\sffamily % Arial type font !

\title{{ Testcase\\ for\\ My Application}}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{flushleft}\textbf {Author} \\
\end{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|L{6cm} L{5cm} L{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Administrator} & Date: &  Signature \\
Some Name & & Electronic Signature on Last Page \\
Another Name & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{flushleft}\textbf {Approvals} \\
\end{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|L{6cm} L{5cm} L{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Manager
} & Date: &  Signature \\
Some Name & & Electronic Signature on Last Page \\
Soem other name & & \\
\hline
\textbf{Quality} & Date: &  Signature \\
Teh QA guy & &  Electronic Signature on Last Page  \\
 & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{INTRODUCTION}
Text
\section{Test case Accountability and Approval}
Here should go text that comes from the database.
% We switch to Landscape here !
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\section{Testing}

% First page, first section - a table that allows to tick a selection
\begin{Form}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|L{6cm} L{6cm} L{5.5cm} L{5.5cm}|}
\hline
\CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ Installation test case} &
\CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ UAT test case} & 
\CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ System test case} & 
\CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ Migration test case} \\
\hline
% \CheckBox{Installation test case}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

% Unique identifier
\hfill \break
\bfseries {Unique Identifier - } Some ID
\newline

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Next table here ...
% Here, we define Run number, Software Version and Change Request ID, if any.
% This table holds editable textfields !
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\arraystretch{0.1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|L{6cm} | L{10cm} | L{7.5cm}| }
\hline
& & \\ % Auxiliary line !
\TextField[width=2cm, bordercolor=white]{Test run number: } &  \TextField[width=2cm, bordercolor=white]{Software Version: } &  \TextField[width=3cm, bordercolor=white]{Change Request: } \\
& & \\ % Auxiliary line !
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|L{5.5cm} | L{9cm}  L{9cm} | }
\hline 
\def\arraystretch{0.1}
& & \\ % Auxiliary line !
Purpose & \TextField[width=18cm, bordercolor=white, name=A0]{}  & \\ 
& & \\ % Auxiliary line !
\hline
\def\arraystretch{0.1}
& & \\ % Auxiliary line !
Test environment / conditions &  \CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ Q-System}  & \CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ P-System} \\ 
& \TextField[width=4cm, bordercolor=white, name=A1]{Server/Database/Client } & \TextField[width=4cm, bordercolor=white, name=A2]{Server/Database/Client } \\
& &  \\ % Auxiliary line !
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable} {|L{2cm} | L{9cm}  L{9cm} | L{2cm} |}
\hline 
Sequence Number & Description & Comments & Present \\
\hline
\endhead
\def\arraystretch{0.1}
& & & \\ % Auxiliary line !
1.1 & Input & \TextField[width=4cm, bordercolor=white, name=X2]{ }  &  \CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ Yes}   \CheckBox[width=0.8em, height=0.8em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56},bordercolor=black]{ No}  \\
& & & \\ % Auxiliary line !
\hline
& & & \\ % Auxiliary line !
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{Form}
\section{Referenced Documents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, will do. But the doc is rather big... I will past this below

Comment: Too big to paste here. I start with Portrait and have some Landscape pages in it. These landscape pages carry the tables.

Comment: I have pasted a short version of the doc into the original post.

Comment: thanks, I'll look (although it's a tricky area....)

Comment: Please make a shorter example. One textfield should be quite enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: And check if this is actually your problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478370/2388

Comment: My problem is rather that the "long table" option does not work. My table stretches over several pages. This is where the problems start. Or there should be a way to use "long table" together with pdflscape - then the TextFiled orientation needs a fix (what KOMAoptions obviously does)

Comment: Ulrike, saw your suggestion regarding the rotation ! Looks good. I will try this. Seems to be the most simple and therefore best solution.

Comment: Ulrike is the winner here ! This solves my problem... mhm and apologise for this "sorta newbie" questions but i have a hard time to find proper documentation that would cover these issues...